# react - copy state to local variable without changing its value

Tags: reactjs

I have a case that I need to update a value in hierarchy state variable (which consists of 3 tree levels in my case, and I need to update a value in third level for example).

I copied that state variable to local variable and did the update on it, but I noticed that state variable was changed as well!

Searched for it, and saw suggestions for using `Object.assign` or Spread operator, I tried using the spread but it didn't help with creating a copy of the state to prevent both objects referring to the same reference but it didn't work!

`Object.assign` appraoch didn't work neither!

Ho can I accomplish that?

```js
const assign = require('object-assign');

// let properties = this.state.configProperties
// let properties =  assign({}, this.state.configProperties)
let properties = { ...this.state.configProperties };

properties.Children.forEach((lvl1) => {
  lvl1.Properties.forEach((property) => {
    if (property.id === id) {
      property.value = val;
      return;
    }
  });

  lvl1.Children.forEach((lvl2) => {
    lvl2.Properties.forEach((property) => {
      if (property.id === id) {
        property.value = val;
        return;
      }
    });

    lvl2.Children.forEach((lvl3) => {
      lvl3.Properties.forEach((property) => {
        if (property.id === id) {
          property.value = val;
          return;
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you try create : Object.create(obj);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Lodash Library for cloning and many more.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

const copy = _.cloneDeep(object)
```

Comment: Worked, thanks. I had a feeling after trying the the spread and object.assign that these libraries will not work because of the deep/shallow cloning as explained in @AppCity answer

Answer (score 3):

You have to clone the nested level objects/arrays as well, in order to avoid referencing original values.

Here is an example on how to achieve deeply nested objects copying,

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const state = {
    dataOne: {
      subDataOne: {
        text: "Test",
        value: "Test One"
      },
      subDataTwo: {
        text: "Test",
        value: "Test One"
      }
    },
    dataTwo: {
      subDataOne: {
        text: "Test",
        value: "Test One"
      },
      subDataTwo: {
        text: "Test",
        value: "Test Two"
      }
    }
  };

  const clonedState = { ...state };
  const clonedData = { ...clonedState.dataOne };
  const clonedSubDataOne = { ...clonedData.subDataOne };

  clonedSubDataOne.text = "New Test Value";

  clonedData.subDataOne = clonedSubDataOne
  clonedState.dataOne = clonedData

  console.log("Original =>",state)
  console.log("Cloned =>",clonedState)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, helped to understand what is really going on. The lodash was easier to use specially when I have a arrays inside my tree hierarchy and not plain fields. Tried marking you answer as "Useful" but I have no enough reputation!

Comment: No Problem, glad you solved your issue :)